# Axios Client Side

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a web page that makes a axios post /users request to create a new user in MongoDB. That call works fine and sets the header x-auth in the response. I can view it on my client side JS. If the request is a success, in client side JS I would like to redirect to a /dashboard page and pass user details so that details of that user is loaded in a JS grid.

I can't wrap my head around how to do this?

Client Side Code Snippet:

```
var signupButton = jQuery('#btn-signup');
var passwordInput = jQuery('#inputPassword');
var emailInput = jQuery('#inputEmail');
var config = {
  headers: {}
};
jQuery('#form-signup').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var password = passwordInput.val();
var email = emailInput.val();
axios.post('/users', {
  email,
  password
})
.then(function (response) {
  config.headers = {'x-auth': response.headers['x-auth']};
  // What do I do here?????
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
});
```

The idea is my redirection url /dashboard should also be authenticated using the authenticate url to avoid people from directly going to that url. So I am hoping, I will redirect from client using a GET request inside the then() of the axios post to /users. The server will authenticate and then render a handlebar template. I don't understand how to do it.

My Server Code Snippet:

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashboard.hbs', {
  pageTitle: 'Home Page',
  welcomeMessage: 'Welcome to my website'
  });
 });
```

**EDIT:**

```
jQuery('#form-signup').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var password = passwordInput.val();
    var email = emailInput.val();
    axios.post('/users', {
            email,
            password
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            config.headers = {'x-auth': response.headers['x-auth']};
            axios.get('/dashboard', config).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                // response.data contains the entire HTML that I want to display in the browser
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

Server:

```
app.get('/dashboard',authenticate, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../views/dashboard.hbs"));
    // res.render('dashboard.hbs', {
    //     pageTitle: 'Home Page',
    //     welcomeMessage: 'Welcome to my website'
    // });
});
```

Comment: add `res.sendFile(__dirname + "nameOfyourPage.html");` to your get request to send the user on authentication.

`app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  
});`

Comment: Why use axios when you have jquery xhr methods available already without another dependency?

Comment: Thanks @ZombieChowder for your response. Should I replace res.render with res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../views/dashboard.hbs")); ? When I did that and sent the request from my client , I get the entire html in response.data. How do I render it?

Comment: @sportsfreak what do you mean exactly by render it??? Just saying *render it* makes no sense.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I mean I simply want to display the page on the browser. But as it stands, I get the entire html of the page I want to display in response.data. Please look at my EDIT.

Comment: @sportsfreak sorry, this makes no sense to me. Do you want to display a specific section or ???